# Why not use `from tf import keras`

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have `import tensorflow as tf`,When I want use `tensorflow.kera`. Why i should `from tensorflow import keras`, instead `from tf import keras`.

Comment: Because one of them does not actually work.

Comment: Please try using both in Colab and you can see that from the library tensorflow you import keras.